# Add a column of repeating numbers to existing dataframe

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe where each row is a unique state-city pair:

```
State  City
NY     Albany
NY     NYC
MA     Boston
MA     Cambridge
```

I want to a add a column of years ranging from 2000 to 2018:

```
State  City.    Year
NY     Albany   2000
NY     Albany   2001
NY     Albany   2002
...
NY     Albany   2018
NY     NYC      2000
NY     NYC      2018
...
MA     Cambridge 2018
```

I know I can create a list of numbers using `Year = list(range(2000,2019))`
Does anyone know how to put this list as a column in the dataframe for each state-city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding it as a list and then performing explode. I think it should work:

```
df['Year'] = [list(range(2000,2019))] * len(df)
df = df.explode('Year')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My `df` is the unique state/city pair. Then I tried the codes above, and got an error `Length of values does not match length of index`. I think it's because we are adding a 18-row column to a df with more rows?

Comment: Thank YOU so much!! It works like a charm. I really appreciate your help!! Never thought there is a command called explode.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method.

Here is sample of your current data:

```
data = [['NY',     'Albany'],
        ['NY',     'NYC'],
        ['MA',     'Boston'],
        ['MA',     'Cambridge']]
cities = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['State', 'City'])
print(cities)

#   State       City
# 0    NY     Albany
# 1    NY        NYC
# 2    MA     Boston
# 3    MA  Cambridge
```

First, make this into a [multi-level index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) (this will end up in the final dataframe):

```
cities_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(cities)
print(cities_index)

# MultiIndex([('NY',    'Albany'),
#             ('NY',       'NYC'),
#             ('MA',    'Boston'),
#             ('MA', 'Cambridge')],
#            names=['State', 'City'])
```

Now, make a dataframe with all the years in it (I only use 3 years for brevity):

```
years = list(range(2000, 2003))
n_cities = len(cities)
years_data = np.repeat(years, n_cities).reshape(len(years), n_cities).T
years_data = pd.DataFrame(years_data, index=cities_index)
years_data.columns.name = 'Year index'
print(years_data)

# Year index          0     1     2
# State City                       
# NY    Albany     2000  2001  2002
#       NYC        2000  2001  2002
# MA    Boston     2000  2001  2002
#       Cambridge  2000  2001  2002
```

Finally, use stack to transform this dataframe into a vertically-stacked series which I think is what you want:

```
years_by_city = years_data.stack().rename('Year')
print(years_by_city.head())

# State  City    Year index
# NY     Albany  0             2000
#                1             2001
#                2             2002
#        NYC     0             2000
#                1             2001
# Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

If you want to remove the index and have all the values as a dataframe just do

```
cities_and_years = years_by_city.reset_index()
```